# Async call of a callresponder

Tags: mysql, actionscript-3, apache-flex, asynchronous, mxml

I have a problem with my `Flex`-Application. As you can see in the code-sample below i try to add some panels to a vgroup. The panels are getting their title from my `MYSQL` db. My problem is that I can't wait on the async call of the `callresponder`, so the panel doesn't get filled. How can I wait for the data from DB?

If i try to build a new panel with a button it works. When i press the button one panel appears with the right title.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
               minWidth="955" minHeight="600" 
               xmlns:produktservice="services.produktservice.*" 
               xmlns:valueObjects="valueObjects.*">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.containers.Panel;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

            private var zaehler:int = 0;

            private function getProduktByID(i:int):void
            {
                getProduktByIDResult.token = produktService.getProduktByID(i);
            }

            private function init():void
            {
                for(var i:int=0; i<10; i++)
                {
                    getProduktByID(818+i);
                }
            }

            protected function getProduktByIDResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                var dynamicPanel:Panel;
                dynamicPanel = new Panel();
                dynamicPanel.id="dynamicPanel"+zaehler;
                dynamicPanel.width=400;
                dynamicPanel.height=200;
                dynamicPanel.title=getProduktByIDResult.lastResult.titel;

                vPanelGroup.addElement(dynamicPanel);
            }


            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                getProduktByID(818+zaehler);
                zaehler++;
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <produktservice:ProduktService id="produktService" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>
        <s:CallResponder id="getProduktByIDResult" result="getProduktByIDResult_resultHandler(event)"/>
        <valueObjects:Produkt id="produkt"/>
        <!-- Platzieren Sie nichtvisuelle Elemente (z.Â B. Dienste, Wertobjekte) hier -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VGroup id="vPanelGroup" gap="10" creationComplete="init()">
    </s:VGroup>
    <s:Button x="726" y="270" label="Button" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Since ProduktService is not a standard Flex class; it is hard to tell what is going on with how you create and send your services or deal with the results.  Perhaps you should share that class.

Answer (score 0):

Is it

```
protected function getProduktByIDResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
{
    var dynamicPanel:Panel;
    dynamicPanel = new Panel();
    dynamicPanel.id="dynamicPanel"+zaehler;
    dynamicPanel.width=400;
    dynamicPanel.height=200;
    dynamicPanel.title=event.result.titel;
    vPanelGroup.addElement(dynamicPanel);
}
```

?